# Having problems with css filling the entire page

Tags: html, css

My title basically says it all. For some reason I cannot get it to stretch the entire page. I am new to this so any help would be great.

[My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti0Ex.png)

This is my html for the code. I have been told that the width and margin needed to be changed from a friend and I tried doing that but got the same results.

```css
.maincontainer{
     width: 990px;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    body {
     background: #B2906F;
     font-family: arial;
     margin: 0;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    .picture{
     display: inline;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     position: fixed;
     z-index: -1;
     background-size: 100%
    }
    
    .button{
     padding: 10px 15px;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background-color: #05280c
    }
    .button-primary:hover {
     background-color: #05370c
    }
    
    h1 {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0;
     background-color: #2c421f;
     padding: 5px;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    ul{
     margin: 0;
     display: inline;
     padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
    }
    ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 15px 10px;
     color: #050c0c;
     margin: 0;
     border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    ul li a {
     color: black;
    }
    
    footer{
     clear: both;
    }
    
    nav {
     color: 
     height: 40px;
     margin: 0;
     background-color: #2c421f;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <div class="maincontainer">
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>NWWolfPack</title>
      <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     </head>
     
     <body>
      <h1>NW Wolf Pack</h1>
      <div class="picture"><img src="camo.jpg" width="1000" height="150">
         <header> 
       <nav>
        <ul>
         <li class="button"><strong>Home</strong></li>
         <li><a href="records.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Records</strong></a></li>
         <li><a href="membership.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Membership</strong></a></li>
         <li><a href="contactus.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
      </header>
     </body>
     
     
     <footer>2017 Dillan Hall</footer>
    </html>
```

Comment: `<div class="maincontainer">` should come after `<body>`. `<html>` is most outer tag. html should contain head and body only.      `<div class="maincontainer">` has `width: 990px;`, so page won't be wider than 990px.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the html in well structured order and make the container div of `with 100%` then it will take the whole width: demo below

```css
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
    background: #B2906F;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0;
}
.maincontainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.picture{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.button{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #05280c
}
.button-primary:hover {
    background-color: #05370c
}

h1  {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2c421f;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

ul{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    color: #050c0c;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li a {
    color: black;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
}

nav {
    color: 
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2c421f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>NWWolfPack</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <h1>NW Wolf Pack</h1>
        <div class="picture"><img src="camo.jpg" width="1000" height="150">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="button"><strong>Home</strong></li>
                        <li><a href="records.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Records</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="membership.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Membership</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <footer>2017 Dillan Hall</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it just shifted it to the left, I even copied all the code in your boxes and tried running it. Its strange because when I run the code on the site it says it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code structure is not correct, I have corrected the HTML structure below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NWWolfPack</title>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

     <div class="maincontainer">
      <div class="picture"><img src="camo.jpg" height="150" style="width: 100%" />
        <header>    
          <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="button"><strong>Home</strong></li>
                <li><a href="records.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Records</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="membership.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Membership</strong></a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    <footer>2017 Dillan Hall</footer>
</html>
```

And to make the screen full size you need to modify your **CSS** code **.maincontainer** and it will solve your issue.

```
.maincontainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it just shifted it to the left. Thanks for responding